# xslt Transformation for value list

Tags: xml, xslt

There are two value lists in source system with values mentioned below (old). In target system, same value lists exist but, with some different values. I need to put XSLT transformation so, old values of source system are transformed properly into target with new values.

Value list

```
01 Secondary_Fraud_Type
```

old values

```
AML
Code of Conduct Breach,
Commission,
Internal,
Misappropriation,
Theft of Funds,
Expenses.
```

Value list

```
01 Secondary_Fraud_Type
```

New Values:

```
AML/Suspicious Transactions,
Code of Conduct Violation,
Commission Scheme,
Internal Theft,
Misappropriation of Funds,
Misappropriation of Funds,
Expenses Travel.
```

Value list

```
02 Primary_Allegation_SubType
```

old Values:

```
Investigative Services - Special Inquiry:441 - Special Inquiry,
Investigative Services - General:298 - Locate.
```

Value list

```
02 Primary_Allegation_SubType
```

New Values:

```
Miscellaneous - Inactive:300 - Verification,
Not Required - Inactive:100 - Closing file,
```

**Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Records count="2">
    <Record parentId="0" moduleId="75"
        levelGuid="b0c2d9a1-167c-4fee-ad91-4b4e7b098b4b" levelId="113" contentId="1010597">
        <Field type="6" guid="34c044c6-b841-4c52-b9f3-b7a56ed7dbd4" id="296">123529</Field>
        <Field type="6" guid="ab6c5129-ed5b-470d-b290-9a7d84123ad3" id="28384">1010597</Field>
        <Field type="4" guid="a0d192ea-9767-4c7e-8a56-4ff973141920" id="24284">
            <ListValues>
                <ListValue id="43156" displayName="Code of Conduct Breach">Code of Conduct Breach</ListValue>
                <ListValue id="43159" displayName="Expenses">Expenses</ListValue>
                <ListValue id="43160" displayName="Forgery">Forgery</ListValue>
                <ListValue id="46729" displayName="AML">AML</ListValue>
            </ListValues>
        </Field>
        <Field type="4" guid="52926f70-9a74-4799-8a14-8d25a1b062da" id="23396">
            <ListValues>
                <ListValue id="43085" displayName="Investigative Services - Special Inquiry:441 - Special Inquiry/Annuity">441 - Special Inquiry/Annuity</ListValue>
            </ListValues>
        </Field>
    </Record>
    <Record parentId="0" moduleId="75"
        levelGuid="b0c2d9a1-167c-4fee-ad91-4b4e7b098b4b" levelId="113" contentId="1011440">
        <Field type="6" guid="34c044c6-b841-4c52-b9f3-b7a56ed7dbd4" id="296">123564</Field>
        <Field type="6" guid="ab6c5129-ed5b-470d-b290-9a7d84123ad3" id="28384">1011440</Field>
        <Field type="4" guid="a0d192ea-9767-4c7e-8a56-4ff973141920" id="24284">
            <ListValues>
                <ListValue id="43157" displayName="Commission">Commission</ListValue>
                <ListValue id="43159" displayName="Expenses">Expenses</ListValue>
                <ListValue id="43161" displayName="Identity Theft">Identity Theft</ListValue>
                <ListValue id="43162" displayName="Internal">Internal</ListValue>
                <ListValue id="43163" displayName="Misappropriation">Misappropriation</ListValue>
                <ListValue id="43164" displayName="Misrepresentation">Misrepresentation</ListValue>
            </ListValues>
        </Field>
        <Field type="4" guid="52926f70-9a74-4799-8a14-8d25a1b062da" id="23396">
            <ListValues>
                <ListValue id="43056" displayName="Investigative Services - General:298 - Locate">298 - Locate</ListValue>
            </ListValues>
        </Field>
    </Record>
    <Metadata>
        <FieldDefinitions>
            <FieldDefinition guid="34c044c6-b841-4c52-b9f3-b7a56ed7dbd4" id="296" alias="Incident_ID" name="Incident ID" />
            <FieldDefinition guid="52926f70-9a74-4799-8a14-8d25a1b062da" id="23396" alias="Primary_Allegation_SubType" name="Primary Allegation Sub-Type" />
            <FieldDefinition guid="a0d192ea-9767-4c7e-8a56-4ff973141920" id="24284" alias="Secondary_Fraud_Type" name="Additional Fraud Types" />
            <FieldDefinition guid="ab6c5129-ed5b-470d-b290-9a7d84123ad3" id="28384" alias="Unique_Tracking_ID" name="Unique Tracking ID-I" />
        </FieldDefinitions>
    </Metadata>
    <LevelCounts>
        <LevelCount count="2" guid="b0c2d9a1-167c-4fee-ad91-4b4e7b098b4b" id="113" />
    </LevelCounts>
</Records>
```

**Expected Output:**  (Replaced with new values)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ex:Record xmlns:ex="http://archertech.com/Print/Export">
    <ex:Item>
        <ex:Incident_ID>INC-123529</ex:Incident_ID>
        <ex:Unique_Tracking_ID>1010597</ex:Unique_Tracking_ID>
        <ex:Secondary_Fraud_Type>
            <ex:Item>Code of Conduct Violation</ex:Item>
            <ex:Item>Expenses Travel</ex:Item>
            <ex:Item>Forgery</ex:Item>
            <ex:Item>AML/Suspicious Transactions</ex:Item>
        </ex:Secondary_Fraud_Type>
        <ex:Primary_Allegation_SubType>
            <ex:Item>Miscellaneous - Inactive:300 - Verification</ex:Item>
        </ex:Primary_Allegation_SubType>
    </ex:Item>
    <ex:Item>
        <ex:Incident_ID>INC-123564</ex:Incident_ID>
        <ex:Unique_Tracking_ID>1011440</ex:Unique_Tracking_ID>
        <ex:Secondary_Fraud_Type>
            <ex:Item>Commission Scheme</ex:Item>
            <ex:Item>Expenses Travel</ex:Item>
            <ex:Item>Identity Theft</ex:Item>
            <ex:Item>Internal Theft</ex:Item>
            <ex:Item>Misappropriation of Funds</ex:Item>
            <ex:Item>Misrepresentation</ex:Item>
        </ex:Secondary_Fraud_Type>
        <ex:Primary_Allegation_SubType>
            <ex:Item>Not Required - Inactive:100 - Closing file</ex:Item>
        </ex:Primary_Allegation_SubType>
    </ex:Item>
</ex:Record>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to use a template approach for converting the old values to the new values and the old nodes to new nodes e.g. `<Record>` to `<ex:Item>` or `<ListValue>` to `<ex:Item>`

```
<xsl:template match="ListValue[@displayName = 'Code of Conduct Breach']" mode="updateDesc">
    <ex:Item><xsl:text>Code of Conduct Violation</xsl:text></ex:Item>
</xsl:template>
```

Below is the complete XSLT to get the output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ex="http://archertech.com/Print/Export">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="Records">
        <ex:Record>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </ex:Record>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Record">
        <ex:Item>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </ex:Item>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Incident_ID -->
    <xsl:template match="Field[@id = '296']">
        <xsl:variable name="elemName" select="concat('ex:', ancestor::Records/Metadata/FieldDefinitions/FieldDefinition[@id = '296']/@alias)" />
        <xsl:element name="{$elemName}">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('INC-',.)" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Unique_Tracking_ID -->
    <xsl:template match="Field[@id = '28384']">
        <xsl:variable name="elemName" select="concat('ex:', ancestor::Records/Metadata/FieldDefinitions/FieldDefinition[@id = '28384']/@alias)" />
        <xsl:element name="{$elemName}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Secondary_Fraud_Type -->
    <xsl:template match="Field[@id = '24284']">
        <xsl:variable name="elemName" select="concat('ex:', ancestor::Records/Metadata/FieldDefinitions/FieldDefinition[@id = '24284']/@alias)" />
        <xsl:element name="{$elemName}">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="updateDesc" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Primary_Allegation_SubType -->
    <xsl:template match="Field[@id = '23396']">
        <xsl:variable name="elemName" select="concat('ex:', ancestor::Records/Metadata/FieldDefinitions/FieldDefinition[@id = '23396']/@alias)" />
        <xsl:element name="{$elemName}">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="updateDesc" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- ListValue -->
    <xsl:template match="ListValue" mode="updateDesc">
        <ex:Item><xsl:value-of select="." /></ex:Item>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ListValue[@displayName = 'Code of Conduct Breach']" mode="updateDesc">
        <ex:Item><xsl:text>Code of Conduct Violation</xsl:text></ex:Item>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ListValue[@displayName = 'Expenses']" mode="updateDesc">
        <ex:Item><xsl:text>Expenses Travel</xsl:text></ex:Item>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ListValue[@displayName = 'AML']" mode="updateDesc">
        <ex:Item><xsl:text>AML/Suspicious Transactions</xsl:text></ex:Item>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ListValue[@displayName = 'Investigative Services - Special Inquiry:441 - Special Inquiry/Annuity']" mode="updateDesc">
        <ex:Item><xsl:text>Miscellaneous - Inactive:300 - Verification</xsl:text></ex:Item>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="ListValue[@displayName = 'Commission']" mode="updateDesc">
        <ex:Item><xsl:text>Commission Scheme</xsl:text></ex:Item>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ListValue[@displayName = 'Internal']" mode="updateDesc">
        <ex:Item><xsl:text>Internal Theft</xsl:text></ex:Item>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ListValue[@displayName = 'Misappropriation'] | ListValue[@displayName = 'Theft of Funds']" mode="updateDesc">
        <ex:Item><xsl:text>Misappropriation of Funds</xsl:text></ex:Item>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ListValue[@displayName = 'Investigative Services - General:298 - Locate']" mode="updateDesc">
        <ex:Item><xsl:text>Not Required - Inactive:100 - Closing file</xsl:text></ex:Item>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Anivet. I ran sample file and it is working fine. I am wondering if I can use the same xslt to run full xml file, which has more fields, value lists, etc in addition to the two fields provided in sample xml code. Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks again

Comment: The solution is based on the input XML shared. I have no idea on how the full XML looks like or the it's content. If there are different values, you would have to tweak this one to get the required output.